# press 'Enter' in the middle of writing a string in c++

Tags: c++, string, newline

I want to write a string and press "Enter" while continuing writing this string, without having to close the "".
For example, i want to write the following line:

```
string drawing = "\\n\\n" +  
"W     W      W        " +  
"\\nW        W  W     W  "  +  
"\\n              '.  W  ";
```

but when i tried to do so, the compiler complains this:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [5]’ and ‘const char [23]’
to binary ‘operator+’
```

Is there a nice way to enter a new line without concating the string (like there is in python, for example, with entering the '\')?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try it without "+".

```
string drawing = "\n\n"
"W W W "
"\nW W W W "
"\n '. W ";
```

Answer (score 3):

You end the string with a backslash:

```
std::string drawing = "\n\n\
W W W \
\nW W W W \
\n '. W ";
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++, when you have two or more string literals only separated by whitespace, they get concatenated. So you can use

```
string drawing = "\n\n"
"W W W "
"\nW W W W "
"\n '. W ";
```